# ASP.NET Maintaining ActiveTabIndex on Postback within TabContainer

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

This probably has been asked many times before but I was wondering how to maintain the ActiveTabIndex of an AjaxControlToolKit TabContainer.

The only way I can think of achieving such a thing is to store the ActiveTabIndex in the session and checking for this on postback. Are there any other solutions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/bc4f7459-4917-4034-957c-6c7f871fa109) answers your question. Such things belong into the ViewState of the Page when their not already saved there.

EDIT:
On the other hand: i've tested it and my ActiveTabIndex maintains on (asynchronous) postback.

Comment: This link will be useful for the future - however I realised the problem was not to do with a postback issue after all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No need to mess with Session on this, Malachi.

Just drop this in your "ActiveTabChanged" event handler (assuming you are using C#):

```
int iTabIndex = int.Parse(Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Split(':')[1]);
```

Then perform whatever logic you need based on the value of "iTabIndex".

Comment: "__EVENTARGUMENT" actually contains "activeTabChanged:#" (where "#" is the index of the tab that was clicked), so I am just parsing out the actual tab index.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add ActiveTabChanged event for tab container and you can keep active tab index in view state, and on page load just check if it is not null then set it as Active tab index.

```
 protected void TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["ActiveTabIndex"] = TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex;

    }
```

PageOnLoad Event code

```
if (!(ViewState["ActiveTabIndex"] == null) )
        {            
               TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = (int)ViewState["ActiveTabIndex"];          

        }
```

Make sure to add following attributes in TabContainer tag

```
AutoPostBack="true" OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged"
```